# How to set site audit report document library location via CSOM

Tags: csom, auditing

I am configuring site auditing via CSOM.  Most of this is easily done via code.  The one piece I cannot figure out, is how to set the document library where the audit reports are stored before trimming occurs.

This is a sample of how I am setting the audit settings so far.

```
using (var context = this.sharePointOnlineAuthenticationHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), siteToken))
{
    var site = context.Site;
    context.Load(site, s => s.Audit, s => s.AuditLogTrimmingRetention, s => s.TrimAuditLog);

    context.ExecuteQuery();
    site.TrimAuditLog = true;
    site.Audit.AuditFlags = AuditMaskType.All;
    site.Audit.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Can anyone provide any insight on how to set the document library where the audit reports are stored before trimming occurs?

Answer (score 5):

A bit late in coming to the party, but in not being able to find the info out there myself thought that I should at least share what I got to work.

The value for the audit report location is stored in a site property which can be easily set via CSOM:

```
private static void setAuditReportLibrary(String targetSiteUrl)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteUrl))
        {

            var web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            var allProperties = web.AllProperties;
            allProperties["_auditlogreportstoragelocation"] = "/site/LibraryName";

            web.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps someone else out :)

Comment: When in doubt, check the property bag. Thanks, this is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Current site collection should be Enabled custom scripting then only Audit properties updated.
Please find below code:

`Using (var tentctx = new ClientContext("TenantUrl"))
{
  tentctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("UserId","pwd");
  tentctx.ExecuteQuery();
  var tenant = new Tenant(tentctx);
  if (IsEnable)
  {
    tenant.SetSiteProperties(targetUrl, noScriptSite: false);
  }
  else
  {
    tenant.SetSiteProperties(targetUrl, noScriptSite: true);
  }
  tentctx.ExecuteQuery();

}

// Audit
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Site site = targetCtx.Site;
    Audit audit = site.Audit;
    targetCtx.Load(site);

    targetCtx.Load(site.RootWeb);
    targetCtx.Load(site.RootWeb.AllProperties);
    targetCtx.Load(audit);
    targetCtx.ExecuteQuery();
    site.RootWeb.AllProperties["_auditlogreportstoragelocation"]= site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/AuditData";
    // Enable all auditing is site collection level
    site.Audit.AuditFlags = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AuditMaskType.All;
    site.Audit.Update();
    // Adjust retention time to be 7 days
    //site.AuditLogTrimmingRetention = 7;
    site.TrimAuditLog = true;

    targetCtx.ExecuteQuery();`